# How to convert an existing eclipse GWT project into a Dynamic Web Project?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, gwt

I am using Eclipse Juno and I have a Java GWT project (SDK version 2.2). I tried setting the project facets to use Dynamic Web Module and also got rid of the GWT dependencies by going to the web toolkit settings and unchecking the selected options.

The project builds fine and bundles the output into a war file. But when I try to run the project on the Tomcat server from within Eclipse, it just doesn't seem to pick up any war file and deploy. What could be the problem here? Am I converting the GWT project to a dynamic web project the right way?

Answer (score 3):

Try this way this may not really what you want but it may helps you, one of the best method that I follow many times. so through this you can debug also GWT module and server module both at a time.

It should probably a little bit easier, but it's possible. Here's how I do it:

1. Setting up the dynamic web project

   File > New > Project... > Web/Dynamic Web Project

   Select the target runtime which is tomcat.

   Important: In Context Root, enter /
2. Adding the GWT module

   Project > Properties > Google > Web Toolkit > Use Google Web Toolkit

   Important: I always need to change the order in the Java Build Path
   (Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export)

   Project > Properties > Google > Web Application: War directory = "WebContent",

   also check "Launch and deploy from this directory"

   Copy your GWT contents to newly created project

   run project as GWT application and also a dynamic web project.
3. Now you can debug both the server and the client part (I still need to click two Debug icons to start both!) I can manage the client side from the "Development Mode" view, and the server side from the "Servers" view.

   At the end of the day, it works great, and using the "Automatically publish when resources change" feature (Servers view > myServerName > Open > Publishing), sometimes even better than with the integrated Jetty.

Comment: Hi Mayank,

Thanks for your detailed response.However my actual objective is to get rid of GWT completely and convert the same existing (GWT) project into a DWP. How should I go about it ?

Comment: this really worked for me - i dont know why the use of gwt is not that much in market - besides we can really develop apps very fast using GWT and GXT